# How to make awk not to skip empty columns?

Tags: linux, awk

Given this input_file:

```
1234 1234 abcd
1234      abcd
```

awk doesn't recognise an empty column, when I run:

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' input_file
```

I get:

```
1234 1234
1234 abcd
```

How to make awk to give me:

```
1234 1234
1234
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about the input format, especially how the columns are delimited

Comment: I dont think that this is straight forward possible . Field delimiter can not be also used as a field.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: If it is tab delimited, that would work fine

Comment: Columns are separated by a space " ", it is not a tab separated file.

Comment: @Code_So1dier OK delimiter is space. Is the middle (missing) column also space or it is a `tab` ?

Comment: The space in the middle is all made of spaces, yes

Comment: Is column width fixed to 4 chars?

Comment: Yes, columns are fixed to 4 characters. I didn't want to go fixed width because there could be a change in field width in the future. But if it is the only way...

Comment: Code_So1dier, I suspect that *is* the best way, `awk` can either use field separators *or* fixed width. If you want to do some combination of the two, you're probably going to have to write your own (rather more complex) code to do it. I say rather more complex because you need *some* way to figure out the column widths if they can change. On second thought, that *is* doable with an `awk` script if you can slightly change the data file, I've updated my answer to show how.

Comment: One solution is to first process each line, for example replace 5 spaces with " 0000" or " ." Or whatever works for your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `awk` program usually uses field separators to decide what characters belong in what fields. If your second line contains only spaces, there's no way to use *that* method to split as you wish.

However, GNU `awk` allows you to set a `FIELDWIDTHS` variable which will better suit fixed-width data, since that appears to be what you have:

```
pax> cat infile
1234 5678 abcd
1234      abcd

pax> awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 1 4"}{print "<"$1","$3">"}' infile
<1234,5678>
<1234,    >
```

It's field one and *three* in this case since field two is the space between the first and second *real* column:

```
1234 5678 abcd
\__/|\__/|\__/
  1 2  3 4  5
```

I usually do that since I don't want the space to become part of the data (in case I want a *different* character in the output as in my example) but, if you're transferring the space anyway, you could also use the simpler:

```
pax> awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="5 4"}{print "<"$1$2">"}' infile
<1234 5678>
<1234     >
```

In that case, field 1 is the *five* characters `1234<space>`.

---

If you want to do fixed width processing but *with* the ability to easily adapt to later width changes, you can modify the `awk` script so it gets that information from the file itself.

Not from the actual data lines since the fields there may have spaces, but you can add a header line to fully specify the widths to use (ensuring the header line isn't treated as data of course).

The following transcript shows this in action (the `awk` script is now in a file since it's getting complex):

```
pax> cat infile
#### ###### ####
1234 567890 abcd
1234        abcd

pax> cat awkfile.awk
NR == 1 {
    # Header: construct field widths string
    #    "a 1 b 1 c 1 d ... z"
    # where a..z are lengths of fields.

    FIELDWIDTHS = length($1)
    for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) {
        FIELDWIDTHS = FIELDWIDTHS" 1 "length($i)
    }
    next
}
{
    # Then use that FIELDWIDTHS string for
    # all other records.

    print "<"$1","$3">"
}

pax> awk -f awkfile.awk infile
<1234,567890>
<1234,      >
```

You'll find that you can change the field lengths as much as you want and, provided the header line is correct, it will adapt.

Comment: Thanks for a descriptive answer. I see that to solve this problem I will need to use a fixed width solution. The original problem is - I'm parsing a hex dump log file. I'm selecting about 10 columns and the troublesome column is at the end. Does it mean I have to specify the field length for every column?

Comment: This is a great solution but allow me to add this comment for people not familiar with `FIELDWIDTHS`. This one `awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 1 4 1 4"}{print "<"$1","$5">"}' file1` will give instructions to awk to handle fields like this: first 4 chars will be field `$1`, next 1 char will be field `$2` , etc. As a result field `$5` will be the last field in both lines, and `print $1,$5` will print first and last field in both lines @Code_So1dier

Answer (score 2):

Having field delimiter ==  field is kind of impossibe. 
You need to consider manipulation of input data.

Here are some examples for fixed width fields:

```
$ awk '{gsub(" [[:space:]]{4} "," ---- ");print}' file1
1234 1234 abcd
1234 ---- abcd
```

You can revert back anytime:

```
$ awk '{gsub(" [[:space:]]{4} "," ---- ");print}' file1 |awk '{gsub("----","    ");print}'
1234 1234 abcd
1234      abcd
```

For a non-fixed width situation, you can use something like this bellow, that will transform a sequence of more than two spaces in something else:

```
$ awk '{gsub(" [[:space:]]{2,} "," - ");print}' file
1234 1234 abcd
1234 - abcd
```

Comment: thats a really good idea, I haven't thought about it before. I will definitely use it for next time. But how would you mask 4 spaces not including the first space?

Comment: @Code_So1dier If you look closer at my awk, you will see that intentionally there is a space before and after `[[:space:]]`. There are also intentionally spaces before & after dash.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most simple approach is to declare the field separator as '\t' (assuming it's indeed tab-delimited).

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $1,$2}' file_name
```

Your code should work now as expected.